# Non-visual Coordinate Grid c#

Tags: c#, grid

I want to create a nonvisual coordinate grid in a c# console application such that I can create a grid that is a set size "aXb" (for example 9X9 or 6X9 etc.). Then, I could assign a number to each coordinate (x,y) and then access it later using those specific coordinates. Every example of a grid that I have seen in c# works explicitly to either make a visual grid with WPF or somehow using characters in a console application. I just want my grid to be saved as data with numbers saved to each (x,y) coordinate. Is it possible to implement this using arrays/lists? Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Actually, I do have an idea of what the code for setting up the coordinates:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int[,] grid = new int[,] { { x }, { y } };
```

Comment: 2 dimensional array/list should do it. Did you even test a solution before coming here?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Grid
{
    public Grid(int width, int length) {
        coordinates = new List<Coordinate>();
        for (int i = 1; i < width + 1; i++) {
            for (int k = 1; k < length + 1; k++) {
                coordinates.Add(new Coordinate(k,i));
            }
        }
    }
    List<Coordinate> coordinates;
    int width { get; set; }
    int length { get; set; }
    public int accessCoordinate(int x,int y) {
        return coordinates.Where(coord => coord.x == x && coord.y == y)
                          .FirstOrDefault().storedValue;
    }
    public void assignValue(int x, int y,int value) {
        coordinates.Where(coord => coord.x == x && coord.y == y)
                   .FirstOrDefault().storedValue = value;
    }
}
class Coordinate
{
    public Coordinate(int _x, int _y) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int storedValue { get; set; }
}
```

And here is just a simple example of how you would use it in a Console Application in this case

```
        Grid newGrid = new Grid(5, 6);
        newGrid.assignValue(2, 3, 500);
        var retrievedValue = newGrid.accessCoordinate(2, 3);
        Console.WriteLine(retrievedValue);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

And just a note, this might not be the most efficient/best way of doing it, but it should simplify it to an extent where it will be easy to modify and understand it quickly